# Is map $f:\mathbb{D}^2\to \mathbb{S}^2$ that fix $\partial \mathbb{D}^2$ surjective on a hemisphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-spaces

I have a map $f:\mathbb{D}^2\to \mathbb{S}^2$ that fix $\partial \mathbb{D}^2$. It seems intuitve believe that $f(\mathbb{D}^2)=\mathbb{S}^2_+$ or $f(\mathbb{D}^2)=\mathbb{S}^2_-$ (hemispheres north and south), but I could not to prove it.

Could you give me a clue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about your assumption? What do you mean by "$f$ fixes the boundary of the disc"?

Comment: I guess that the boundary of the disk is mapped to the equator of $S^2$

Comment: I think the OP is identifying $\Bbb{R}^2$ with a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ in the standard way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there are two points not in the image of $f$, one on the North emisphere and one on the South emisphere. Removing the two points, up to homeomorphism you get a map

$$\hat{f} : D^2 \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$$

That maps the boundary to a generator of the fundamental group on the right. This is impossible, because an element of the $\pi_1$ extends to a disk precisely when it is trivial.

On the other side, it is possible to have a surjective map with the constraints you prescribed. Firstly, let me notice there is a surjective function $g: D^2 \to S^2$ that maps the boundary to the South Pole: this is kind of "put a disk on a sphere and then collapse the boundary to the South Pole. A similar one can be done with North Pole, that we call $g_1$.

Now define $f: D^2 \to S^2 $ as:

$$ f(x) = g(2x) ,\quad \|x \| \le 1/2$$
$$ f(x) = g_1 \left ( \frac{x}{\| x \| } \left (\|x\| - \frac{1}{2} \right ) \right ) , \quad 1/2 \le  \|x\| \le 1 $$

You can verify that it satisfy your constraints. Use yous imagination!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am reading doing other works (I mean, did not put down the formulas to study), but I imagine that is something like the explanation of Rob Arthan right down, right?

Comment: Please, could you explain me why $\hat{f} $ maps the boundary to a generator of the fundamental group on the right? Thank you so much (I understand the names, but is my first time on algebraic topology).

Comment: It was because the closed path on cilinder is not homotopic to a cnstant? Thank you

Comment: Yes! You got the first argument, which shows that one of the two hemispheres will always be in the image. The boundary is mapped to a one clock tour around the cylinder, which is not homotopic to a constant. On the other hand, an extension to the disk can be thought as an homotopy to a constant: for a fixed radius $r$ you will find the image of the circle at time $r$: at 1 you have the original circle, while at zero you have a constant. The surjection is nicely explained by the other answer: it is the same "sock map" of Rob Arthas!

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry by bothering. I have a doubt on second part of formula. When $||x||=1/2$, so $1-2/||x||=-3$ and you get $f(x)=g_1(-6x)$, but $-6x\not\in \mathbb{D}^2$...? Thank you and sorry if I mistaked

Comment: There was a mistake! It's on me. Now it should be more manifest how the formula acts: the direction is the same, but the norm is shifted by 1/2.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Think of $\Bbb{S}^2$ as the surface of a tennis ball and think of $\Bbb{D}^2$ as a sock of about the same diameter as the tennis ball. Put the tennis ball in the bottom of the sock with the south pole at the toes and tie a piece of string around the sock so that it neatly traps the whole tennis ball with the knotted string at the north pole. Now fold the rest of the sock into tucks so that the edge fits snugly around the equator of the tennis ball (if you choose a short enough sock you will only need one fold). This gives you a picture of a surjection of $\Bbb{D}^2$ onto $\Bbb{S}^2$ that identifies $\partial\Bbb{D}^2$ with $\Bbb{S}^1$ in the standard way.

Comment: It's a really nice manner to explain, thank you so much